# $L_p$ norm of a gradient

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

For a given smooth function $u$, let $Du$ denote the gradient of $u$.

Then, Evan in his PDE book (appendix A, pg 702) defines the $L_p$ norm of $Du$ as

$\|Du\|_{L_p}= \| |Du|\|_{L_p}$, where $|Du|$ (according to his notation on pg 701) is given as $(u_{x_1}^2+u_{x_2}^2+\dots + u_{x_n}^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

But, why does he use the $L2$ norm of a gradient in defining the $Lp$ norm of the gradient?

Wouldn't it make more sense to define $\|Du\|_{L_p}$ as $\| |Du|_p\|_{L_p}$, where $|Du|_p$ denotes the $L_p$ norm, instead of the $L_2$ norm?

Comment: Because this definition is invariant under rotations (and of course translations) of the coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a finite dimensional space the $p$-norms are all equivalent. Up to a constant, $\| |Du|_q\|_p$ and $\||Du|_r\|_p$ are the same, so it is convenient to use the familiar definition of $|Du|$ as the Euclidean length of $Du$ since, as Hans Engler points out, it has very nice invariance properties.

Comment: In Sobolev space setting, doesn't one usually use $\||Du|_p\|_p$

Comment: You can, after all they are equivalent.